# display: none to null using bookmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to convert this:

```
<div class="AAA-BB-CCCCCC" data-lock-id="ABC12345" style="display: none;">
```

To this:

```
<div class="AAA-BB-CCCCCC" data-lock-id="ABC12345" style="display: null;">
```

`12345` can be different every time. The main point is just to convert none to null with bookmark link.

Like this:

```
javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null)
```

If I click on above bookmark link, it re-enables right-click when web pages turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your CSS

```
 .AAA-BB-CCCCCC {
     display:null !important;
  }
```

or include it directly in your HTML code like this

```
  <style>
     .AAA-BB-CCCCCC {
        display:null !important;
     }
  </style>
```

You need the !important to over rule the inline display property.